# MongoDb and Net Topology Suite

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I save entities with geometric properties (like NTS) with mongo db?

```
using GeoAPI.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

public class Area
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Polygon Extent { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to save the object I get the

> "Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?)."

exception (NTS does have circular references in its objects). Is there a way to by pass it?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geo-overview-location-data

Comment: I use NTS..it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [write a custom serializer](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#write-a-custom-serializer). Such serializers are also included in the C# driver code itself, for instance in the [CultureInfoSerializer](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/CultureInfoSerializer.cs) (.NET Culture Infos have cyclic references, plus you only want to store the actual locale code, not all the derived information).

The source code of the `CultureInfoSerializer` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: But if I create a custom serializer I will not be able to use the spatial index.

Comment: Well, the custom serializer should store the data in a format that is compatible to the spatial index convention mongo expects. In case of coordinates, that might entail not only a simple format conversion, but also a coordinate transformation. It's debatable whether you'd like to do that in the serializer because a non-skew-invariant conversion would yield a strange query behavior, but then again, if you'd need a querying behavior that isn't supported in MongoDB, you're in trouble anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for a solution, I have created [MongoDB.NetTopologySuite.Serialization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.NetTopologySuite.Serialization) package which adds support for serializing/deserializing NetTopologySuite models to BSON and back.